# Three.js Quaternion cannot assign to read only property

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a class (with three.js) that uses an array with vector names compare to an array with a set of vectors 3 and generates the mesh of the flat face, but I'm getting an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'quaternion' of object '# <Tface>'
    at Tface.criaFace (Tface.js: 58)
    at eval (index.js: 54)
    at Module ../ src / index.js (bundle.js: 651)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js: 674)
    at bundle.js: 738
    at bundle.js: 741
```

https://github.com/gisselecardozo/teste-classes/blob/master/src/classes/Tface.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `Tponto` is derived from `THREE.Object3D`. The resulting `quaternion` property is read-only. Meaning the following assignment in your `criaFace()` method is invalid.

> this.quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(this.normal, this.baseNormal);

It should be:

> this.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(this.normal, this.baseNormal);

Comment: I'm having another problem now. I'm using this class to display faces of a solid in a site, but when i call the class the faces shapes appear in other places with different rotations.
I tryed to change the baseNormal to a (0,0,0) vector and faces goes to right place and rotation, but the vertical faces dont show and i got an  error 
THREE.DirectGeometry: Faceless geometries are not supported

Comment: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/L6Qa75w

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/vVSG5wQ

Comment: Please create a new question for this.